# Why is the default collation not applied in PostgreSQL queries?

Tags: postgresql, collation, locales

- OS: Windows 10
- Docker OS: Alpine Linux 3.18.3
- DB: PostgreSQL 15

I created a new PostgreSQL database named test1 with zh-x-icu as the default collation using the following command:

`postgres=> create database test1 with encoding 'UTF8' owner db_owner lc_collate 'zh-x-icu' lc_ctype 'zh-x-icu' template template0;`

When I list the databases, the datcollate and datctype columns show the expected values:

| datname | datdba | encoding | datcollate | datctype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| template1 | 10 | 6 | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
| template0 | 10 | 6 | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
| postgres | 10 | 6 | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |
| test1 | 43170 | 6 | zh-x-icu | zh-x-icu |

However, when I run queries in this database, the sorting behavior doesn't align with the default collation zh-x-icu. Here are some examples:

| query | result |
| --- | --- |
| SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('张'), ('李'), ('王'), ('赵'), ('刘')) AS names(name) ORDER BY name; | 刘张李王赵 |
| SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('张'), ('李'), ('王'), ('赵'), ('刘')) AS names(name) ORDER BY name collate "en-x-icu"; | 刘张李王赵 |
| SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('张'), ('李'), ('王'), ('赵'), ('刘')) AS names(name) ORDER BY name collate "zh-x-icu"; | 李刘王张赵 |

As you can see, the query without explicit collation returns the same result as the one with 'en-x-icu', which is not what I expected. I expected it to behave like the 'zh-x-icu' query since that's the default collation for the database.

Why is this happening, and how can I make the default collation apply to queries in this database?

**Here is the docker-compose**:

```
version: '3'
services:
  timescaledb:
    image: timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg15
    hostname: d16f59bcb903
    mac_address: 02:42:ac:11:00:02
    environment:
      - PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
      - LANG=en_US.utf8
      - PG_MAJOR=15
      - PG_VERSION=15.4
      - PG_SHA256=baec5a4bdc4437336653b6cb5d9ed89be5bd5c0c58b94e0becee0a999e63c8f9
      - DOCKER_PG_LLVM_DEPS=llvm15-dev clang15
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumes:
      - H:\DB_PG15:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: "no"
    labels:
      maintainer: "Timescale https://www.timescale.com"
    runtime: runc
```

Comment: Can you share the docker-compose?  With a bare-bones one, I don't get that locale existing.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

`LC_COLLATE` and `LC_CTYPE` (or shorter: `LOCALE`) are for C library locales only.

The reason that your statement does not cause an error is probably because Alpine Linux uses musl as its C library, whose locales have ICU-like names. But [the last time I looked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58135353/6464308), musl's collations didn't work as they should, which probably explains what you see.

Use a Linux distribution with a working C library, or use PostgreSQL's support for the ICU library (if that is available on Alpine Linux, and your PostgreSQL is built with ICU support):

```
CREATE DATABASE test1
   OWNER db_owner
   ENCODING UTF8
   LOCALE_PROVIDER icu
   ICU_LOCALE zh
   TEMPLATE template0;
```

Comment: If it were just a matter of musl being broken, wouldn't it be broken in the same way between a db's default collation and an explicitly specified collation?

Comment: @jjanes I don't think so. The names of musl locales just are the same as the names of ICU collations. If you build PostgreSQL with ICU support, it will link with `libicu.so`, which is a different library that will provide working collations, even if the collation names are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Laurenz Albe's answer and [Jezk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58135353/6464308), I managed to solve the issue with collation for Chinese characters in PostgreSQL running in a Docker container. Here's how:

Step 1: Create a docker-compose.yml File

```
version: '3'
services:
  timescaledb:
    container_name: timescaledb-pg15-zh
    image: timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg15
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: "--locale-provider=icu --icu-locale=zh_CN"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - "<your_data_directory>:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

Step 2: Run the Docker Compose Command
Execute the following command in the terminal:

```
docker-compose -f "<path_to_your_docker-compose_file>" up -d
```

After doing this, the collation settings for Chinese characters behaved as expected.